# How to position an element so that it's anchored in its center

Tags: html, css

The goal is to position an element so that when the user hovers, it grows (by increasing it's padding) from the center out. I tried this but no luck:

```
<div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Go</a>
</div>

div {margin:100px; position:relative; background-color:#ddd;
     display:inline-block; padding:100px; }

a   {font-size:30px; height:50px; width:50px; border-radius:50%; 
     background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5); padding:20px;
    position:absolute; margin:-45px 0 0 -45px; text-align:center;}

a:hover {padding:30px;}
```

Any ideas?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7zqqs60s/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by using `transform: translate(-50%,-50%);` instead of `margin`

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7zqqs60s/4/)**

```
a {
    font-size:30px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding:20px;
    position:absolute;

    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);

    text-align:center;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}
```

**For More Info:**

> CSS transform - [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

### [EDITED]

**Solution 2:** Set `margin:-55px 0 0 -55px;` to `a:hover`

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7zqqs60s/9/)**

```
a {
    font-size:30px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding:20px;
    position:absolute;
    margin:-45px 0 0 -45px;
    text-align:center;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}
a:hover {
    padding:30px;
    margin:-55px 0 0 -55px;
}
```

Comment: You could also add a transition to the anchor declaration to smooth the change, for instance: transition:padding 0.4s ease;

Comment: Thanks to @ErnestoVera [CSS Transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) DEMO - http://jsfiddle.net/7zqqs60s/5/